# Doubling metrics, doubling measures, Lebesgue density

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, real-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

As stated in this question,
[Lebesgue differentiation theorem holds on locally doubling space?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/218457/lebesgue-differentiation-theorem-holds-on-locally-doubling-space)
and proved here,
http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~tyson/595f15lecture2.pdf
the Lebesgue differentiation theorem (LDT) holds in doubling measure spaces.
It is also known that every complete doubling metric supports a doubling measure:
http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1998-126-02/S0002-9939-98-04201-4/S0002-9939-98-04201-4.pdf

[From this I conclude that if $\mu$ is a probability measure on a complete doubling metric space $(X,d)$ and $\mu\ll\nu$, where $\nu$ is a doubling measure (whose existence is guaranteed), then $\mu$ is itself a doubling measure and hence satisfies the LDT. **EDIT**: this is false, ignore.]

Does the LDT hold for probability measures on complete doubling metric spaces? (Can additionally assume $(X,d)$ is compact if needed.)

Comment: I don't think I agree with the second paragraph.  Let $X = [0,1]$ with its usual metric, let $\nu$ be Lebesgue measure (which is doubling) and let $\mu$ be the probability measure with cdf $F(x) = e^{1-1/x}$.  Then $\mu \ll \nu$ but $\mu$ is not doubling.

Comment: Ack, I see my mistake. Do you agree that the 2nd paragraph holds if I additionally assume $\nu\ll\mu$?

Comment: I believe my counterexample still applies.  Note that the density $d\mu/d\nu$ is $F'(x)$ which is a.e. strictly positive.

Comment: Oh I see. I had mistakenly assumed that $F'(x)$ blows up at $0$, but now I see this isn't the case. I'll edit the question to remove that paragraph -- but the main question remains for now.

Comment: Right.  It's true that $d\nu/d\mu = 1/F'$ blows up near 0 but that's not a problem, it's still in $L^1(\mu)$.

Comment: I think I understand the source of my confusion in the 2nd paragraph -- I had confused $\mu\ll\nu$ with the stronger condition $||d\mu/d\nu||_\infty<\infty$. When I assume that both Radon-Nikodym derivatives are essentially bounded, the doubling property of $\mu$ follows, yes? But of course, that's not the main question I'm after...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A version of Lebesgue differentiation for non-doubling measures on doubling metric space appears in section 3 of:

T. Hytonen, A FRAMEWORK FOR NON-HOMOGENEOUS ANALYSIS ON METRIC SPACES, AND THE RBMO SPACE OF TOLSA
http://www.raco.cat/index.php/PublicacionsMatematiques/article/download/191394/387513

I leave it to your judgment whether this is of use to you.