# Where does the Lebesgue differentiation theorem fail?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces

The Lebesgue differentiation theorem says that for certain metric spaces $X$ (see below), any Borel measure $\mu$ that is finite on bounded sets and any $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ locally $\mu$-integrable, there is $A \subseteq X$ s.t. $\mu(X \setminus A)=0$ and

$$\forall x \in A: \lim_{r \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\mu(B_r(x))} \int_{B_r(x)} f(y) \mu(dy) = f(x)$$

Here, $B_r(x)$ is the ball of radius $r$ with center $x$.

This holds for $X$ a Riemannian manifold or $X$ a locally compact separable ultrametric space. I'm interested to understand how it fails on somewhat more general spaces. In particular:

- Can the theorem fail on $X$ a compact separable metric space? Can you provide a counterexample (i.e. $X$, $\mu$ and $f$ s.t. the identity fails)?
- Is there a compact Polish space $X$ s.t. the theorem can fail for *any* metrization of $X$ (i.e. for any metrization there are $\mu$ and $f$ s.t. the identity fails)?

Comment: These questions are relevant: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/244665/doubling-metrics-doubling-measures-lebesgue-density

Comment: and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/218457/lebesgue-differentiation-theorem-holds-on-locally-doubling-space

Comment: Could it be that you misquoted something in your opening paragraph? If I compare it with the wikipedia article for example, then the corresponding claims are only made about the Lebesgue *density* theorem there.

Comment: Which part do you find dubious? For Riemannian manifolds I think that the theorem follows quite easily from the Euclidean case by considering a local diffeomorphism with $\mathbb{R}^n$ (resulting eccentricity will be bounded on compact sets).

Comment: @Squark: I think we are having some basic misunderstandings here and in the comments to my answer below. The point I'm trying to make (here and below) is that already on $\mathbb R^2$, it is certainly not true that $|A|^{-1} \int_A f(x-t)\, dt \to f(x)$ for a.e. $x$ as $\textrm{diam}(A)\to 0$, $0\in A$, if the sets $A$ get too general, and eccentricity is the problem. For example, you can't allow general rectangles. Maybe it would be helpful if you stated precisely what statement exactly you're interested in rather than just refer to it as the Lebesgue differentiation theorem.

Comment: @ChristianRemling, see recent edit.

Comment: @Squark: Thanks for the clarification, this is very helpful I think. I'm still not sure about the other point I raised: do you have a reference for the claims in your (now) second paragraph? (As I said, if it's taken from the wikipedia article, I think you are in fact misquoting it.)

Comment: @ChristianRemling: In "Derivations and Martingales" (Hayes and Pauc, 1970), page 20 we have Theorem 2.3 which says that differentiation works as long as our family of sets satisfies the "Vitali property." On page 30 we find Theorem 1.2 which says that the Vitali property is satisfied iff the *density* theorem holds. So, unless I misunderstand something, the density and differentiation theorems are more or less equivalent.

Comment: For $\mathbb{R}^n$ and arbitrary Borel measure, the theorem appears in "The Metric Entropy of Diffeomorphisms: Part I" (Ledrappier and Young, 1985), see Lemma 4.1.2 there. I think that the generalization to arbitrary Riemannian manifolds shouldn't be hard because for a Riemannian metric the balls have locally bounded eccentricity w.r.t. the Euclidean metric. For ultrametric spaces I think the Vitali property should follow from the fact that any two balls are either disjoint or one contains the other.

Comment: The case of $X = \mathbb{R}^n$ and arbitrary $\mu$ is also covered in "Measure Theory vol. I" (Bogachev), see Theorem 5.8.8.

Comment: @Squark: Thanks for these references. I'm not doubting any of this, but let me just point out that if you consider more sets, then there are situations where the theorem holds for $f\in L^p$, $p>1$, but not for general $f\in L^1$. A concrete example is given by rectangles with sides parallel to the coordinate axes in $\mathbb R^2$. See Stein, Singular integrals... . So there is a difference between the differentiation and density theorems in general.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: This is interesting, unfortunately I don't have access to Stein's book so I can't see the details. I think that the apparent contradiction might come from the fact that Theorem 2.3 in Haus and Pauc requires the Vitali property both wrt $\mu$ ad wrt $f \mu$, whereas in Stein's example the density theorem is satisfied for the Lebesgue measure but (maybe?) not for other measures absolutely continuous wrt the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @Squark: Stein's book actually does not have any details, the result is just quoted there. Saks's book mentions it too (again without details). The original paper seems to be Jessen, Marcinkiewicz, Zygmund, Fund. Math. 1935.

Answer (score 3):

I assume by *Lebesgue differentiation theorem* you mean the statement that $|B(x)|^{-1}\int_{B(x)} f(y)\, dy \to f(x)$.

Then it's not clear to me what your set-up on $X=[0,1]^{\mathbb N}$ is (what's the measure?), but in any event, for an *arbitrary* metric, this already fails on $\mathbb R^2$. You can take a metric that gives you wide thin rectangles as small balls, for example
$$
d(x,y)=\max (|x_2-x_1|, |y_2^{1/3}-y_1^{1/3}|)
$$
(if $y<0$, then $y^{1/3}$ just means $-|y|^{1/3}$).

**Update:** This answer was originally based on my recollection of the "standard fact" that the higher-dimensional Lebesgue differentiation theorem fails for rectangles if the eccentricity is not restricted. This much is true if arbitrary rectangles are allowed, but of course the situation here is different, and I'm not sure now what the situation is (and in fact I'm not even sure it's not an open question).

Comment: Thanks for answering, Christian!

Regarding $[0,1]^\omega$: I meant that I want a counterexample with *any* measure.

Regarding $\mathbb{R}^2$: the equation you wrote is not a metric since the "distance" between $(-1,0)$ and $(+1,0)$ vanishes. I guess you meant to e.g. take the half-plane $x \geq 0$? But this is isomorphic to the usual $L^1$ metric (transform by $x' = x^2$)?

Comment: (also, I realized that what I really need to know is "Is there a compact Polish space s.t. for *any* metrization there is a counterexample?", but I guess it's too late to rephrase the question)

Comment: @Squark: No, I wanted a metric whose balls are rectangles with unbounded eccentricity, see my new version please.

Comment: OK, and what is $f(x,y)$?

Comment: Your new construction is still isomorphic to the usual $L^1$ metric via the transformation $y' = y^{\frac{1}{3}}$. Moreover, any construction that has bounded eccentricity in some neighborhood of any point except for a set of zero measure cannot work (of course we can also start playing with measure, but I don't know how).

Comment: I agree with Squark, I don't think this answer is correct. The Lebesgue density theorem fails for the collection of all rectangles. It holds for the collection of rectangles with axis-parallel sides, so it is not a matter of eccentricity alone (I think it is an open problem to determine for which sets of directions $A$, the Lebesgue density theorem holds for all rectangles with long side in direction $A$, but it definitely holds if $A$ is finite)

Comment: @PabloShmerkin: I'm not very happy with your wording here. Your comments are relevant and much appreciated, but what you say is almost exactly what I wrote myself in my update, so I find it a bit harsh to summarize this by saying my answer is incorrect.

Comment: @PabloShmerkin: Also, the Lebesgue *differentiation* theorem (which is what the question is about) fails for the collection of rectangles with sides parallel to the coordinate axes, see Stein, Singular integrals ..., I.5.3.

Answer (score 0):

The classic reference book is:

[Hayes & Pauc](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3642861822), *Derivation and Martingales*